# SQL Query: Filter duplicate entries by getting the entries with the maximum id number then join another table's data with it

Tags: sql, knex.js

I am trying to get all id, std_name from table1, and all id, score from table2 where std_id of table2 matches the id of table1 and deleted_at should be null for all entries of table1 and table2. But table2 can have duplicate std_ids, in that case, I only want the entries with the maximum id number from table2.

Sample table1:

| id | std_name | deleted_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jhon | null |
| 2 | sam | null |
| 3 | joe | null |

Sample table2:

| id | std_id | score | deleted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | null |
| 2 | 2 | 20 | null |
| 3 | 1 | 30 | null |

So far I have tried using this query:

```js
const query = knex.select([
    't1.id as t1id',
    't1.std_name as name',
    't2.score as score'
])
.from('table1 as t1')
.leftJoin('table2 as t2', function () {
    this.on('t2.std_id', '=', 't1.id')
})
.joinRaw('left join (select MAX(id) as id, std_id from table2 group by std_id) as kst on kst.std_id = t2.std_id');

query.where({'t1.deleted_at': null}).orderBy('t1.id')
```

Results generated for the above query:

| id | name | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jhon | 30 |
| 2 | sam | 20 |

But this only returns the maximum id entry of the duplicate entries from table2 and omits the entries of table1, but I also want the ids from table1 which are not included in the std_id of table2.

My desired output:

| id | name | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jhon | 30 |
| 2 | sam | 20 |
| 3 | joe | null |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions.  In SQL this looks like:

```
select t1.*, t2.score
from table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t2.std_id order by t2.id desc) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t2.std_id = t1.id and t2.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: your suggested query is returning all duplicate entries from table2 and doesn't return entries from table1.

Comment: @RaiyanRashidProdhan . . . The query as written returns all rows from `table1` and exactly one matching row from `table2`.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake on my part. It's working perfectly now. Thanks a lot for your assistance.